# AngularJS CSV file reader

Tags: angularjs, csv

I am trying to read CSV files. I was going to upload into server memory and then read the contents of the file, but I stumbled upon this:

```
.directive('csvReader', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            csvReader: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $(element).on('change', function (changeEvent) {
                var files = changeEvent.target.files;
                if (files.length) {
                    var r = new FileReader();
                    r.onload = function (e) {
                        var contents = e.target.results;
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.fileReader = contents;
                        });
                    };

                    r.readAsText(files[0]);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now this would work perfectly on my site if it didn't use jQuery.
Does anyone know how to read a CSV file without needing jQuery?

Comment: hah, I just did this last week. Do you need it to actually upload? I am using this https://github.com/bahaaldine/angular-csv-import and it worked fine if you don't need to upload it

Comment: Yeah I found that, but I modified it a bit to work with what I need.

Comment: so you're good then?

Comment: Yeah, got that part solved now. Posted another question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this to work by reverse engineering https://github.com/bahaaldine/angular-csv-import.

My directive looks like this:

```
.directive('csvReader', [function () {

    // Function to convert to JSON
    var convertToJSON = function (content) {

        // Declare our variables
        var lines = content.csv.split('\n'),
            headers = lines[0].split(content.separator),
            columnCount = lines[0].split(content.separator).length,
            results = [];

        // For each row
        for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

            // Declare an object
            var obj = {};

            // Get our current line
            var line = lines[i].split(new RegExp(content.separator + '(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)'));

            // For each header
            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {

                // Populate our object
                obj[headers[j].trim()] = line[j];
            }

            // Push our object to our result array
            results.push(obj);
        }

        // Return our array
        return results;
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            results: '=',
            separator: '=',
            callback: '&saveResultsCallback'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // Create our data model
            var data = {
                csv: null,
                separator: scope.separator || ','
            };

            // When the file input changes
            element.on('change', function (e) {

                // Get our files
                var files = e.target.files;

                // If we have some files
                if (files && files.length) {

                    // Create our fileReader and get our file
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    var file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];

                    // Once the fileReader has loaded
                    reader.onload = function (e) {

                        // Get the contents of the reader
                        var contents = e.target.result;

                        // Set our contents to our data model
                        data.csv = contents;

                        // Apply to the scope
                        scope.$apply(function () {

                            // Our data after it has been converted to JSON
                            scope.results = convertToJSON(data);

                            // Call our callback function 
                            scope.callback(scope.results);
                        });
                    };

                    // Read our file contents
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: How then do you use the above in html?

Comment: just add the attribute to a file input and then do something with the response: `<input type="file" csv-reader complete="controller.validateResults(results)" />`